# Unable to build Solidity Compiler in Aion FastVM

Tags: virtual-machine, blockchain, solidity, ubuntu-18.04, aion

I'm using the steps on the FastVM guide to build it. I'm stuck on the part where you have to build the Solidity compiler. I've installed the prerequisites but when I run `make` I get the following:

```
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./libsolidity/interface/ABI.cpp:21:0:
./libsolidity/interface/ABI.h:25:10: fatal error: json/json.h: No such file or directory
 #include <json/json.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./libsolidity/interface/Exceptions.h:27:0,
                 from ./libsolidity/interface/ErrorReporter.h:25,
                 from ./libsolidity/interface/ErrorReporter.cpp:23:
./libdevcore/Exceptions.h:20:10: fatal error: boost/exception/exception.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/exception/exception.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
^CMakefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Interrupt
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Prerequisites: it looks like you're still missing the Boost library and a JSON library. Have you installed the -dev versions of the packages? Could you link to the guide you're following

Comment: Hi Sarah, welcome to Stack Overflow! I have a feeling that it's because you're running this on Ubuntu 18.04 (not sure if you meant to include that tag). I'm just spinning up a 16.04 VM just to check if I get the same error messages.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Aion FastVM is built to run on Ubuntu 16.04, not 18.04. Here's the steps I took to get it up and running. I used the steps on [Aion's Github](https://github.com/aionnetwork/aion_fastvm) for reference.

1. Spin up a Ubuntu 16.04 x86-64 environment (either locally or on AWS / Azure / DigitalOcean / etc).
2. SSH into your new environment and run the following **line-by-line**:

`cd ~
git clone https://github.com/aionnetwork/aion_fastvm.git
sudo apt install build-essential llvm-4.0-dev
make
cd solidity
sudo apt install build-essential libboost-all-dev libjsoncpp-dev
make`

3. Reboot the VM: `sudo reboot now`.

I did get a few warnings while building the Solidity compiler, but they were just warning. Nothing was terminated.